# c# datagridview and mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am doing some c# and mysql and I was successful at getting mysql data into a grid view for the first time! Now, my main question is, how do I manage the grid view style with this? For example, say I have already created columns and such, how do I put the mysql data into a specific column in the grid view?

Below is the code that is actually loading the data into the grid view.

```
 try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                // - DEBUG 
                // MessageBox.Show("Connection successful!"); 
                MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `swipes`", conn);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MyDA.Fill(table);

                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                bSource.DataSource = table;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource; 

            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Close(); 
            }
```

Also, this creates columns based on the mysql data, how do I modify the width of these columns and such, or like stated above, use my own custom columns for my data? I've never done any mysql work in any UI, so I'm open to suggestions and tutorials as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: go for entities... you can thank me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this (as someone has already stated you should look at other options) you can create the columns in the designer and set the `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName` on each column to the columns returned by the autogenerated dataset. Remember to turn of autogeneration of columns (`AutoGenerateColumns`) on the grid. This way you have full control of the column styles.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string connection = "server=localhost;database=adil;user=root;password=";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = con;
        MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from studentrec";
        MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, con);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MyDA.Fill(table);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = table;


        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
```